# How to add a progress bar showing the level of a person

Tags: discord.js

I've looked everywhere for a tutorial for this but had no luck.

What I'm trying to do is that lets say if a person has 10/100 XP I want it to show like a image progress bar.

Comment: You might want to add the result you'd like. But the easiest solution I can see is dynamically generating an image and upload it to the text channel.

Comment: Create an image using any package you like and send it using an embed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ill answer my 3 year old question as this post still receives views.
I'd advise using [node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) as it's the best way to generate a buffered image to send.

1. Create a canvas (follow the tutorial via the README.md)
2. Set the width to something of your choice (ex. 500px)
3. Set the height to something of your choice (ex. 20px)
4. Calculate the percentage of the XP (ex. 10/100 would be .1 or 10%)
5. Fill the canvas with a height of the canvas, along with a width of the percentage (in decimal) multiplied by the width of your canvas.
6. Color the canvas that you filled to your choice (Should be prior to filling)
7. Enjoy your image generated progress bar!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a bar for every one XP. You show them based on what they have. There aren't implemented features for progress bars.